# Excel VBA - Userform textbox formatting causing rounding errors

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user form with 3 text fileds. `txtCurrentSum`, `txtTargetVal` and `txtDelta`. I've initialized textbox values when the form opened.

`delta` should be zero, but the `txtDelta` textbox is showing `4,99999999999545E-03`

How can I circumvent this stiuation?

```
'Variable Definitions
Private originalSum As Double
Private targetSum As Double
Private precision As Integer
Private delta As Double

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    originalSum = 311.135
    targetSum = originalSum
    delta = targetSum - originalSum

    precision = 2      
    txtCurrentSum.Text = Format(Hammer.originalSum, "#,##0.00")
    txtTargetVal.Text = Format(targetSum, "#,##0.00")
    txtDelta.Text = Format(delta, "#,##0.00")

End Sub
```

I didn't set number formatting in the form's objectView/Properties because I'll change them programmaticaly.

---

Found the problem in other subroutine. Apparently `Sub txtTargetVal_AfterUpdate()` event is triggering when I initialize the textboxes. `delta` was updated in this sub. I add `round` here to fix the problem.

```
' Target Value Changed
'
Private Sub txtTargetVal_AfterUpdate()
    targetSum = CDbl(txtTargetVal.Text)
    txtDelta.Text = targetSum - originalSum
End Sub
```

Here I changed `txtDelta.Text = targetSum - originalSum` with `txtDelta.Text = Round(targetSum - originalSum, precision)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want two decimal places on your output, write

```
txtDelta.Text = Format(Round(delta, 2), "#,##0.00")
```

instead of `txtDelta.Text = Format(delta, "#,##0.00")`

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the source of the problem in another sub but fixed with your method. I'am adding the details in question.